# Wordpress email not sent to user but sent to admin

Tags: wordpress, email, registration

I'm encountering some issues with my wordpress setup.

When a new user is registered a mail is sent to the admin to notify him that an user registered. But the user do not recieve the password.
I do not see where is the issue :( ! Can you please assit me on fixing this?
I'm loosing customer ...

Comment: can you please upload your `Code` ? Can't just tell by looking at your question.

Answer (score 0):

I used the plugin TML: Theme My Login all issue solved